# MYSQL /PHP Find common couples in dataset of collection/groups

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dataset of "collections" or let's call them groups or wishlists...
a collection is a list of items

```
    collectionId |  itemdId
---------------------------------

        123      |    2345
        123      |    3465
        123      |    876
        123      |    567            
        123      |    980

        777      |    980
        777      |    332
        777      |    3465
        777      |    876
        777      |    678
        777      |    567
```

you see item 876 and 980, are included in both collections (777 and 123) so they are a popular couple/pair

my users generate these collection, and I'm curious to extract two insights:

> 1. which are the most common items (this is easy)
> 2. which are the most common pairs/couple (or more than 2) of items (this is my question)

eg.

> say many wish-lists contains iphones and a pink iphone covers
>   among other accessories but i want to extract in fact that iphone +
>   that pink iphone cover is a common recurring "couple"

all in all, basically i'm trying to do what Amazon does, if you see an iphone i want to suggest you a pink iphone cover because many other users have suggested/favorited that

Do I have to compare similarity between collection first? to see who many items they have in common? than rate the similarity with an index?

what is the best approach to this with mysql. 
do i need PHP as well?

**UPDATE:**

in PHP I would probably do something loopy like in pseudo code

```
for total number of collection:

select all item from collection 1

  select all item from collection 2
  do array_interesct (c1,c2)
  store the matching items
  repeat...

  select all item from collection 2
  do array_interesct (c1,c3)
  store the matching items
  repeat...

...then elect all item from collection 2 and repeat all the iterations..
```

Comment: how you define a couple  .. two items?  or somethings others?

Comment: We need to see the table(s) where the data is stored to know how to make those pairs or couples. The "table" you posted only includes numbers.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez my table is just numbers, that's it... than i have a separate table with names atc, but is is not influential in this case

Comment: @scaisEdge yes couple = two items = pairs. common pairs like shoes and sock, or iphone and iphone cover... something that users usually save in their cart or in their wishlist very likely

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez table names? collectionId and itemId are table names... i don't understand your questions...

Comment: @Francesco  . instead of use new terms if you can do a sample with item number  like in your question

Comment: you see item 876 and 980, are included in both collections (777 and 123) so they are a popular couple/pair

Answer (score 1):

For two  collection you can do a join

```
select a.itemID
from my_table a
join my_table b on a.itemID = b.ItemID
where a.collection = 123
and b.collection = 777
```

for all you can try with a cartesian product (for pair two table)  .. for ( 3 ..3)

```
select a.itemID
from my_table a
cross join my_table b 
where a.item = b.item
and a.collection <>  b.collection
```

Comment: i have only one table... just one table... column, collection, and autoincremental generic tableID... period...

Comment: You see that is just one table in selft join using alias .. or not .. and i hope this is not the motivation for downvote

Comment: what is a.item = b.item? whenever did I use this term?

Comment: one column is called collectionId, one column is called itemId...

Comment: If you don't know a self join and an alias .. you should  learn because are  really important  for combinatory calculation like you need for this question

Comment: the example above works, but i need a version that scans all the collections, which can be thousands, the second example doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I have udapte the answer for the second query .. adding the condition taht the two collection must be different ... hope is useful .. let me know